# VueJs docker image not loading in the browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, dockerhub

**QUESTION:** (edited: solution is added at the end of this post)

I have VueJS project (developed in webpack), which I want to docker-size.

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:8.11.1 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

which is basically following the flow from [this post](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html).

I also have a .dockerignore file, where I copied the same files from my .gitignore and it looks like:

```
.DS_Store
node_modules/
/dist/
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

# Editor directories and files
.idea
.vscode
*.suo
*.ntvs*
*.njsproj
*.sln
.git/
```

I have created a docker image with the command:

```
 docker build -t test/my-image-name .
```

and then run it into a container with the command:

```
 docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --rm --name my-container-name test/my-image-name
```

as a result of this last command, I got the same output in the terminal (which is normally showing in cases of debugging with webpack / vuejs) as when I run the app locally:

[image]

**BUT**: at the end, in the browser window [the app is not loaded](http://prntscr.com/l1g6vn)

If I run the commands `docker images` and `docker ps` I can see that the image and the container are there, and while creating them, I did not got any error messages.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285857/nodejs-app-doesnt-connect-to-localhost-when-running-within-a-docker-container/48286174#48286174) and had a few tries for changing the Dockerfile as:

Option 1

```
FROM node:8.11.1 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .    
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["ng", "serve", "-H", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Option 2

```
FROM node:8.11.1 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["ng", "serve", "-H", "0.0.0.0"]
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

But it seems none of them is working.

btw. my package.json file looks like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  }
```

**So I'm wondering:** how to make the app to be opened in the browser from the docker image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401606/vuejs-drag-and-drop-example-in-docker-not-working/52403618#52403618

Comment: Please post container logs: `docker log <container id>`

Comment: I found the solution and edited the post to contain the answer as well

Comment: It would be a better idea to post it as an answer and accept it (one of the reasons being Google indexing).

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. Even when including the EXPOSE 8080 line in the docker file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** not, sure if this was the reason for the fix, but I did two things. As mentioned, I'm working with the VueJS and webpack, so inside of the file named `config/index.js`, which initially looked like:

```
module.exports = {   
  dev: {    
    // Paths
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {},

// Various Dev Server settings
host: 'localhost', // <---- this one
port: 8080,
```

I changed the `host` property from `'localhost'` into `'0.0.0.0'`, removed the `EXPOSE 8080` line from the Dockerfile (the initial Docker file from my question above) since I noticed that the port from the config file is used by default and also restarted the installed Docker tool on my local machine.